# How can I load a matlab object of which the class definition file was placed in separate package

Tags: matlab, class, object

Is it possible in matlab to load an object of which the class definition file was placed in separate package?

For example:

```
T = myTestClass;
save('T');
```

Now I want to place my class in a package, so I create the directory structure as follows:

```
+myTestPack/@myTestClass/myTestClass.m
```

Next I try to recover the saved object:

```
import myTestPack.*
load('T.mat');
```

The outcome is always:

```
Warning: Variable 'T' originally saved as a myTestClass cannot be instantiated as an object and will be read in as a uint32.
```

Is there any way to solve this problem? I would like to restructure my code but a lot of old data was saved as objects. 
Maybe I need to add loadobj/saveobj methods to the definition file or maybe there is a way to rename the class from myTestClass to myTestPack.myTestClass?

Thank you for your suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add loadobj method to your new class. You also need a simple class myTestClass in the old location with just a loadobj method which calls loadobj method of the moved class. MATLAB does not know that you have moved the class. When loading all it knows is that it is of class type myTestClass and tries to create one by looking up myTestClass.